# Forçar reescrita de do titulo de uma pagina

Tags: php, html

Bem tenho uma pagina, porem uma dessas paginas queria que mudasse o titulo.
Exemplo minha pagina usa no Reader um código que define o titulo de todas as pagina, mas tenho uma pagina em php personalizada que também quero colocar um titulo diferente, ou seja Reescrever o titulo que já e definido no Reader, existe alguma forma em PHP ou qualquer outro de fazer isso ?

```
<?php   
include_once "./includes/header.php";   
 <!-- AQUI VAI MEU CONTEÚDO -->  
include_once "./includes/footer.php"; 
?>
```

Seria tipo isso, mas eu não posso editar o header.php
Ai tera que forçar mudar o titulo pelo oque esta no `<!-- AQUI VAI MEU CONTEÚDO -->`

Comment: Você pode postar o trecho do código. Pois isso deve ser feito basicamente usando uma estrutura condicional.

Comment: Pronto, coloquei um exemplo em codigo!

Comment: Você pode alterar esse arquivo : `"./includes/header.php"; `  ?

Comment: Não, pq e um script pronto jah!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você consegue fazer isso utilizando JavaScript ou jQuery, porém seria melhor se você optasse por editar diretamente no `./includes/header.php`.

Em JavaScript:

```
document.title = 'Novo título';
```

jQuery:

```
$('title').text('Novo título');
```

Uma outra solução, que acredito que também possa ser feita de uma maneira melhor. Seria você no `./includes/header.php` onde você define o título passar uma variável ao invés de um texto estático como:

Usando tags **curtas**:

```
<title><?= $page_title ?? "Título estático" ?></title>
```

Usando as tags  tradicionais:

```
<title><?php echo $page_title ?? "Título estático"; ?></title>
```

Nesse exemplo, se eu não me engano, ele faz a verificação se a variável `$page_title` existe usando a função `isset`, se ele existir, seu valor é passado, senão, "Título estático".

E dessa forma você adicionaria a variável antes do `./includes/header.php` dessa maneira:

```
<?php
// Define o título aqui.
$page_title = 'Título da página';

include_once "./includes/header.php";   
<!-- AQUI VAI MEU CONTEÚDO -->  
include_once "./includes/footer.php"; 
?>
```

Comment: Como posso colocar essa função em PHP $file->originalFilename dentro do "Novo título" ?

Comment: @MatheusVitor Se o que você quer é adicionar o texto de `$file->originalFilename` para JavaScript/JQuery pode fazer assim: `<?= $file->originalFilename ?>` (Substitua "Novo título" por esse trecho), ou se você quer fazer isso com o exemplo em PHP é só atribuir o valor como você normalmente faz: `$page_title = $file->originalFilename;`.

Comment: No meu Header.php tem esse código dentro da tag title: `<?php echo validation::safeOutputToScreen(PAGE_NAME); ?>`

Comment: @MatheusVitor A constante `PAGE_NAME` é a que define o título? Se for você pode usar o exemplo em PHP: `<?php echo validation::safeOutputToScreen($page_title ?? PAGE_NAME); ?>` e então definir antes do `header.php`, provavelmente também dá pra você fazer isso com a constante, porém seria menos certo ainda, pois constantes devem ser constantes e imutáveis.